# Does Synergy work over internet instead of local network?

Tags: synergy

I want to Synergize my computers on work, but 2 of them is in different networks and domain controlled with limited network port availability. Is it possible to connect them "over cloud"?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd connect them the same way you'd connect anything else that expects a lan connection. VPN or other networking tools.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, at the moment there's no way to connect via the 'cloud'.

BUT, this is coming soon! We're looking into Synergy Cloud and hopefully, we'll have something to show soon.

Source: I work for Symless, the Synergy developer.

Comment: Soon... soon...

Comment: @fixer1234 How's the best way to show I'm a Symless employee? :)

Comment: Exactly like you did.  :-)

Comment: still no luck about cloud version?
my MACBOOK doesn't have access to the same wifi network as desktop work station

Comment: 5+ years later, any updates to this?